# Match elements containing both specific text and any number of any digits

Tags: xpath, xpath-1.0

I'm looking for an XPath 1.0 query that would look somewhat like this:

```
//*[contains(text(), 'EXAMPLE') and translate(text(), translate(text(), '0123456789', ''), '') != '']
```

But the problem with this query is that there is no longer the text "EXAMPLE" after it performs the second part of the query, so it ultimately fails.

What I need is to match all elements that contain both the text "EXAMPLE" and any number of any digits.

I'm using Octoparse and it only supports XPath 1.0. Is that possible to achieve at all? I've tried asking ChatGPT a thousand times about this, but it keeps giving me the same illogical queries like the one above, which cannot work due to violating basic logic.

Comment: Could you provide a sample XML so the question complies with a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided your source XML, so it's not possible to be sure why your query doesn't work for you. My guess, though, is that your bug is due to the behaviour of the `translate` and `contains` functions when their first parameter is a nodeset containing more than one item. The [String Functions section of the XPath 1.0 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#section-String-Functions) says:

> A node-set is converted to a string by returning the string-value of the node in the node-set that is first in document order. If the node-set is empty, an empty string is returned.

So if your XML looked like this:

```xml
<root>
   text node 1
   <child>blah</child>
   EXAMPLE 123
</root>
```

... then the following expression would return `false`:

```xpath
contains(text(), 'EXAMPLE')
```

... because the expression `text()` would return *two* text nodes which are children of `<root>`, and the `EXAMPLE` text is contained in the *second* of those text nodes.

Perhaps you should be checking the *string-value* of the elements themselves, rather than the value of their first text node? If you pass the element itself as the first parameter to the string functions, then that will be converted to a concatenation of all the text nodes contained within that element (including inside child elements). In XPath 1.0 it's not possible to concatenate just the child text nodes and exclude the text nodes within child elements.

e.g. you could try:

```xpath
//*[contains(., 'EXAMPLE') and translate(., translate(., '0123456789', ''), '') != '']
```

NB the result of this expression would include not just the leaf elements for which this is true, but also all the ancestors of that element, right up to the root element. To exclude those ancestor elements, you could use this expression:

```xpath
//*
   [contains(., 'EXAMPLE') and translate(., translate(., '0123456789', ''), '') != '']
   [not(
      *[contains(., 'EXAMPLE') and translate(., translate(., '0123456789', ''), '') != '']
   )]
```

That would exclude an element whose text value matched your criteria if it also contained a child element whose text value matched those criteria.

Comment: That's exactly what was going on, and I would never find out what to do without your help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: could you please provide the same query as the last one in your solution, but so it would make "EXAMPLE" case-insensitive and only match elements where "EXAMPLE" is either the first word in a string or it's both preceded and followed by a space or any punctuation mark (i.e. .,:;?!()#)? I would love to submit a new question instead, but I can't even word the question correctly and I doubt it will pass moderation.

Comment: @PriceMitchell I think you do need to ask a new question. See this page for how to ask a question <https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask> and this page about how to make a workable example <https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example>. Make sure you include example input _and_ desired output because this helps to show how you want each particular kind of input handled, where just explanations can be confusing if there are many edge cases.

Comment: I've created a question and worded it the best I could, my brain just doesn't work any better than that. No wonder it got to the staging ground: https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/75909328. Maybe you could take a look?

Comment: I see a 404 on your new question

Comment: I didn't know that nobody except me could see Staging Ground questions. Anyway, now it has been published: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75915215/match-elements-containing-both-a-specific-case-insensitive-whole-word-and-any-nu